# Multiplying Rational Expressions

Tags: rational-numbers

[image]

I'm stuck on this equation. These are the steps I've done so far:

[image]

And after this I'm stuck. 1 - 8? It makes no sense. I have no clue about what I did wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it was actually $1-8$ then you can replace it with $-7$ since that is what $1-8$ is equal to... in actuality, there is a typo and it should have been $1\color{red}{a}-8$, not $1-8$ since you factored out a $2$ from both top and bottom of the fraction on the left.

Comment: I'm confused.  If 1-8 makes no sense, then why the heck did you do it?  Is this your answer or someone elses?   Anyway.  $\frac {6a^2 -48a}{2a-16} =\frac {6a(a-8)}{2(a-8)}=3a\frac {2(a-8)}{2(a-8)} = 3a$.

Comment: You dropped the a in "48a"-- it completely disappeared for no reason.  And you dropped the a in "2a"-- it completely disappeared for no reason.  What *does* factor out of both is 2 so you gate $\frac {3a^2- 24a}{a - 8}$  Then you can see that $2a$ factors out of the top to get $\frac{3a(a-8)}{a-8}$ which... you can see you can "cross out" the "a-8".

Comment: Oops.  Never mind.  That's a plus/not minus on top.  Factoring we get:  $\frac {2*3a*(a+8)}{2*(a-8)} *\frac {(a+7)}{(a+7)(a+8)}$.  Canceling we get $\frac {3a}{a-8}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the mistake is in the first line: $$\frac{2(3a^2+24a)}{2(a-8)}=\frac{3a^2+24a}{a-8}$$

Comment: OK. So the final answer should be 3a/a-8?

Comment: the final answer is $$\frac{3a}{a-8}$$ if $$a\ne 8$$

Comment: no it is $$\frac{3a}{a-8}$$

Comment: Yeah, you are right.  I misread the top of the left hand term.